# How to create the hooks directory

Tags: svn, svn-hooks

We have a pre-existing SVN repository. Whoever created it did not follow the SVN standard directory structure and so there is no hooks folder.

Is there a way to tell SVN to regenerate the hooks folder? If not, is there a way to create a directory manually and configure SVN to use that folder?

Comment: Where are you looking, exactly? Hooks don't exist inside the repository itself where you can see them from a client. They're a child of the directory created when your admin ran `svnadmin create`. The only way it's not there is if it was intentionally deleted.

Comment: As I said, this is a pre-existing repo that I did not create. I can only assume that the hooks directory was either not created or was deleted at some point.

Comment: Are you looking at the directory structure on the server, or only the repository contents through a client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `mkdir hooks` should do. Be sure to give the various scripts the exec bit; and have them executable by the svn (webserver) user.

If you want to example scripts; simply do

```
mkdir temp-example-copy-of-repo
cd temp-example-copy-of-repo
svnadmin create repo
cd repo/hooks
```

to get the example templates.

Comment: Thanks, I think this should be good. It's a bit tough finding straightforward info about hooks. Does the folder even matter or does SNV just look through the whole repo for files with the right name (eg. post-commit)?

Comment: SVN doesn't look in the repository for hooks at all. They're in a separate directory outside the repository contents.

Comment: Thanks Dirk for this answer.
But If I create hook locally and put a batch file in that then every other user of repository have to do the same, I guess.
Also in my case,repository was created at enterprise level so no access to admin user. Is there any way I keep hook at one place which will be accessible to all?.